# How to get all days from a date range and group by those days?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

So I have a table like the following.

```
user_id      start_date      end_date
1            2020-06-14      2020-06-16
2            2020-06-15      2020-06-17
....
```

I want to get something like this

```
date           user_ids
2020-06-14     1
2020-06-15     1,2
2020-06-16     1,2
2020-06-17     2
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 and 9.4 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You may try joining a calendar table to your current table, and then aggregate by day:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('day', dd)::date AS date
    FROM generate_series
    ( '2020-06-14'::timestamp 
    , '2020-06-17'::timestamp
    , '1 day'::interval) dd
)

SELECT
    d.date,
    STRING_AGG(t.user_id::text, ',' ORDER BY t.user_id) AS user_ids
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON d.date BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date
GROUP BY
    d.date
ORDER BY
    d.date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

If you need to expand the range of the calendar table to cover more actual data, then just edit the CTE and change the starting and ending dates.